# How can I generate random numbers given I have probability of varous ranges specified in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random, probability

I want to fill in the dummy data of attendance. I want that,for example, 60% students have attendance in the range of 70-100,25% in the range of 40-60 and 15% in the range of 0-40. How can I generate this using random numbers in Python. Is there any inbuilt function for this?
I know that numpy.random.choice allows to predefine the probabilities of discrete numbers but is there any way to specify probabilities of bins/ranges?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number N of students, you can take

```
N_ha = int(N * 0.6)  # students with high attendance
N_la = int(N * 0.15)  # students with low attendance
N_aa = N - ha - la  # students with average attendance

att_ha = np.random.random(N_ha) * 0.3 + 0.7  # this creates N_ha attendances in the half-open range [0.7, 1)
att_la = np.random.random(N_la) * 0.4
att_aa = np.random.random(N_aa) * 0.2 + 0.4  # sure you didn't mean between 40 and 70? in that case, substitute 0.2 with 0.3

attendances = x = np.append(att_ha, np.append(att_la, att_aa))
np.random.shuffle(attendances)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.interp` like so:

```
>>> ranges = [0, 0.4, 0.7, 1.0]
>>> probs = [0.15, 0.25, 0.6]
>>>
# translate to cumulative probabilities
>>> P = np.r_[0, np.cumsum(probs)]
>>> 
# draw and transform
>>> samples = np.interp(np.random.random((1_000_000,)), P, ranges)
>>>
# check 
>>> np.count_nonzero(samples < 0.4)
149477
>>> np.count_nonzero(samples > 0.7)
600394
>>> np.count_nonzero((samples < 0.7) & (samples > 0.4))
250129
```

The sub populations will be uniformly distributed in their ranges.

`np.interp` creates a piece-wise linear function. Used as we do here it chops up uniformly `[0, 1]` distributed samples into groups `0-15%`, `15-40%` and `40-100%` and rescales them into `0-40%`, `40-70%` and `70-100%`.